# Flutter SFdatagrid on editing the table scrolls to the top

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

The problem is that If i have few rows in the datagrid it is all ok, but if I have lots of them and I scroll to go to the latest rows when I tap to edit a cell, the keyboard correctly appear but the table scroll to the top. I want the table don't scroll to the top in the moment that I edit a cell in the latest rows.

I know is needed a license, and I have it. I need that someone can help me to understand why this scrolling to the first cell happen when i try editing and the keyboard appear. If it could help there is support documentation about editing https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/editing. I read it but I can't found what I need to solve the problem.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.